# Using different models for one view for GET and POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen multiple answers on this so I'm really confused.

Using one single view, can you use one model for the GET action and a different model for the POST? As an example, here's what I've got--here's an example of a ViewModel I have:

```
public class ModelAViewModel {
    public ModelB modB { get; set; }
    public ModelC modC { get; set; }
}
```

I currently use ModelAViewModel to do a GET to display data from ModelB and ModelC. I was wondering if I could also do a POST of just ModelB and then make a new object of ModelC in the POST function.

Might be bad coding standards, but a new requirement of a feature came in to display ModelC's data, and I was wondering if this was possible without refactoring.

Comment: Yes you can, but if its not working for you, then you need to show your code - both the view and the method your posting to (we can't guess what your doing wrong)

Answer (score 0):

In general, always just go for it. If it *doesn't* work, then you can ask for advice, but just try it and see what happens.

Since you're here already, though, I can tell you that this is fine. If you don't post anything for `modC`, it will just be null on POST. Also, the model validator doesn't validate null instance properties, so you can still have required properties and such on `ModelC` and as long as you don't post anything at all related to it, you won't get errors.

Comment: This is all within the same.View, correct? Because if I try to pass in a ModelB into my POST function, it's coming up as null. Using ModelA to display data is fine. It's just using/passing ModelB to submit is coming up null.